# Passing a view model to helper class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, helper

I would like to display a tag cloud in my test application using a helper class to create the html.

I can use a for each loop in the partial view to visit each item in the model

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl < IEnumerable < MyTestproject.Models.TagCount > >

foreach (var item in Model) {

}
```

But when I try to pass the model to the Helper class and use a for each loop I receive the following error:

```
public static string DisplayCloud < TagCount >(TagCount objTags) {

..
       foreach (var item in objTags) {

       }
}
```

foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'TagCount' because 'TagCount' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

What is the difference or am I passing it incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're passing a different type.

The view is getting `IEnumerable<TagCount>`

The helper is getting `TagCount`

Your helper code needs to be:

```
public static string DisplayCloud(IEnumerable<TagCount> objTags) {

..
       foreach (var item in objTags) {

       }
}
```

The generic type on the method seems useless/illegal, since it's an actual type, so I removed it, as well as fixing the argument type.

Comment: Made the change, ran the code and of course it works a treat. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Look more closely at the difference between your view's class signature and your helper method's signature:

> Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<**IEnumerable**<MyTestproject.Models.TagCount>>
>
> public static string DisplayCloud<TagCount>(TagCount objTags)

The method needs to receive an `IEnumerable<TagCount>` in order to call foreach.

Comment: Thanks, but how do I pass it correctly I am currently using the following: <%= TagCloudHelper.DisplayCloud(Model) %>

Comment: You are passing it correctly assuming Model is an IEnumerable<TagCount>, however your method signature needs to be modified to accept that parameter.

Comment: Unfortunately I not sure how to do that, do you mean something like this?: public static string DisplayCloud IEnumerable<TagCount>(TagCount objTags)